# Why is useQuery in apollo client not actually getting the data?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client

I am having strange situation with React routing with GraphQL. I have a users in `/users` url and when i go to users page for the first time `useQuery` is working, request is going to the server and bringing me some data. Then, if i go to another page and come back to the users page, `useQuery` is not working and request is not going to the server. `useQuery` is working and request is going to the server when i reload the page. Here is my code and query for Users component:

> `Users.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLazyQuery, useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { USERS} from './queries'


const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([])
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USERS);


const Users= () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const result = data?.users?.payload.filter(item => item.status === "waiting" && !item.isDeleted)
    setUsersList(result)
  }, [loading, data])

  return (
    <div>
      {usersList?.map(user => (
        <div key={user.key}>
          <h1>{user.name}</h1>
          <p>{user.status}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
)
}
```

> `queries.js`

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const USERS= gql`
query{
  users(size: 50){
    payload{
      key,
      isDeleted,
      status,
      name,
      ...
    }
  }
}`
```

So, final question, why useQuery is working only one time when site is reloaded, not rerendered?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design –– your query's results would have been stored in Apollo Client's cache the first time that query triggered. If the query's variables haven't changed, then the query won't actually travel the network again, Apollo Client will pull the data out of its cache instead.

You could change the `fetchPolicy` on your `useQuery` hook if you want the request to go over the network to your server every time your hook is run: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#supported-fetch-policies

Answer (score 0):

You can use *useLazyQuery* and *useEffect* for that
[useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery)

```
const [runQuery, { data, loading, called }] = useLazyQuery(yourQuery);

useEffect(() => { runQuery(); }, [location]);
```

I think you will get the idea ;)

EDIT: also you can change FetchPolicy on the normal to *network-only* query (I think this should work too):
[params of useQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy)

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my question. I know  useLazyQuery but i wanted to know that is it possible to call that runQuery with useQuery. And I found `refetch` for that in useQuery,and it is working perfectly. So, thank you one more time